# How to call a Class from another folder inside component folder?

Tags: php, class, yii, components

I am using Yii 1.1.12 I have a class something like this:

***project_folder/protected/components/myfolder/ClassA.php***

```
class ClassA {

  public function getData() {
     return 'data';
  }

}
```

How to call ***getData()*** of ***ClassA*** from controller or from any other Class?

Comment: Did you set up this component inside your Yii configuration file?

Comment: no, i want to access it directly from controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work
    Yii::import('application.components.myfolder.ClassA');
    echo ClassA::getData();

Answer (score 1):

Here example:

```
// /protected/components/A.php
class A extends CApplicationComponent
{

    public function getData()
    {
        return 'data';
    }
} 

//main config.
'components' => array(
        // ...
        'a' => array(
            'class' => 'application.components.A'
        ),
```

How to use:

```
echo Yii::app()->a->getData();
die();
```