# Yii variables in Codeception 1.8 tests

Tags: yii, codeception

i've been wondering if there is a way to use constants/variables from Yii in codeception tests (cests and/or cepts).

Im talking about Yii::app()->... or some properties from the Yii models.

Im using yii 1.14 and codeception 1.8

Comment: Maybe this help you: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940774/how-to-call-a-class-from-another-folder-inside-component-folder/31946393#31946393)

Comment: @DanilaGanchar That won't work as i need to call Yii from inside the codeception tests, not the other way around.

Comment: as I understand, you want in codeception tests use Yii components? Is it right?

Comment: I have not worked with codeception. How you start tests? From console?

Comment: Yes, tests are started from the console. Here is an example: ProjectRoot > php common\vendors\codeception\codecept.phar run api -c api/protected/codeception.yml

Comment: I haven't checked this. But maybe this can help you: [this module provides integration with Yii framework](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Yii1). I see in example yii use like module: `$els = $this->getModule('Yii1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out you can load yii (the same way its loaded in your index file) in _bootstrap.php, you just don't need to call Yii::app()->run(); at the end of it.

Not sure if its the correct way, but so far thats the only working way i know of.